# F# compilation without msbuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, f#

how do I simulate, from the command line, compiling an F# file with fsc.exe:

- without resorting to msbuild explicitly
- setting the framework version to another one of my choosing (for example .Net 3.5)

?

So far it seems that I need to make a project at all costs, but that is simply not an option in my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by simulate you mean, how do I build F# files with fsc.exe, you can just pass through files in the order that they are referenced to fsc.exe.

If you had the following files

*Message.fs*

```
module Message

let customMessage = "Hello, from message"
```

and *Hello.fs*

```
module Hello

open System
open Message

let main args =
  printfn "%s" customMessage
  0
```

You compile those with (something like):

`'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Fsc.exe' C:\dev\Message.fs C:\dev\Hello.fs`

**Edit**

In order to compile this referencing a specific version, you need to update your references as per @nicolas response.

You need to specify `--noframework` and provide FSharp.Core and mscorlib.

I was able to do this using the FSharp reference assemblies. For whatever reason, I needed to be in that directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp`)

I could then run this:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Fsc.exe' --out:c:\dev\Hello.exe --noframework -r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll -r:"2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll" C:\dev\Message.fs C:\dev\Hello.fs
```

Comment: Thanks, but I explicitly mentioned setting the framework version in my question. That does not seem covered in your answer, but is my biggest issue...

Comment: The framework is coming from the FSharp.Core you link to. for reference, core 2.0.0.0 = F#2.0, donet < 4.0, core 4.0.0 = F#2.0, dotnet 4.0, core 2.3.0.0 = F#3.0, dotnet <= 4.0, core 4.3.0.0 = F#3.0, dotnet 4.5.

Comment: I am having trouble by specifying mscorlib.dll (v2.0) along side FSharp.Core...I get a BadImageException...

Comment: BadImage makes me think of bitness, but I see you already posted a question on this.